# target two HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to target two html in one javascript and I have no idea if that is even possible

I tried giving ids and classes to the html tag but it doesnt work. i have an image that I want it to be clickable do direct users to another html and gave it and id and tried targeting it in js but it still doesnt work. i have tried the a href tag but its not what i want.

```
$(function(){
  $("#close1").on("click",closepage);
})

function closepage() {
  // console.log(checkUi);
  $("#space-3").css("display","block");
  $(".chat__main").css("opacity", "0");
  $("#chat-content").css("opacity","0");
}
```

I want to close the second and third HTML which is `.chat__main` and `#chat-content`

To be clearer, I would like to target different IDs from three different HTML. Everything is in the same folder, linked with the same javascript

this is the third HTML for an example. main.js is the js im working with. I want to close this HTML when users clicked on the "close" button.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no'>
<title>HybriD </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
</head>
  <body class="chat">

    <div class="chat__sidebar">
      <h3>People</h3>
      <div id="users"></div>
    </div>

<div class="chat__main">
      <div class="topChat">
          <img src="img/cross.png" id="close1">
        <h3 id="chatTitle">HybriD Chat</h3>
      </div>
      <ol id="messages" class="chat__messages"></ol>
      <div class="chat__footer">
        <form id="message-form">
          <input name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" autocomplete="off"/>
          <button id="submit-btn"><img src="img/send.png" alt="Send" height="50" width="50"></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script id="message-template" type="text/template">
      <li class="message">
        <div class="message__title">
          <h4>{{from}}</h4>
          <span>{{createdAt}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="message__body">
          <p>{{text}}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/mustache.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the second HTML. This is the two HTML that I want to target to close. Am I targeting the wrong IDs?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no'>
    <title>HybriD </title>
    <meta name="description" content="Basic Example — Networked-Aframe">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vendor/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vendor/load.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/hamburgers.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="favicons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <script src="js/vendor/aframe-master.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/aframe-mouse-cursor-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/socket_io.js"></script>
    <script src="easyrtc/easyrtc.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/network-aframe.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/aframe-particle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="centered-form" id="loginpage">
        <div id="chat-wrapper">
            <div id="chat-content">
               <svg id="home-logo2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 344.74 321.88"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ececec;}.cls-2{fill:#07f;}.cls-3{fill:#ffce2e;}</style></defs><title>Asset 2</title></svg>

<!--        <input type="image" id="close1" src="img/cross.png">-->
        <img src="img/cross.png" id="close1">
        <div id="login" class="centered-form__form">
            <form action="/chat.html">
            <div class="form-field"><h3>Join Chat</h3></div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Display Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">

                <input type="text" name="room" placeholder="Room Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                <button>Join</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
             </div>
            </div>
<script src="js/vendor/AVideoPlayer.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.Wload.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>    
</body>
```

for the main HTML, it is very complicated. The first page the users see will be a login page. After they have logged in, they will be directed to an image called "#space-3" which i want to direct the users there.
this is the main HTML for my website:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no'>
    <title>HybriD </title>
    <meta name="description" content="Basic Example — Networked-Aframe">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vendor/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vendor/load.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/hamburgers.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="favicons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <script src="js/vendor/aframe-master.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/aframe-mouse-cursor-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/socket_io.js"></script>
    <script src="easyrtc/easyrtc.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/network-aframe.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/aframe-particle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="error">
      <img id="disconnect-icon" src="img/disconnect.svg" alt="">
      <p class="error-msg">
        Disconnected from the server.
      </p>
      <p class="error-msg">
        Please refresh the page.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="home-wrapper">
      <div id="home-content">
        <svg id="home-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 344.74 321.88"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ececec;}.cls-2{fill:#07f;}.cls-3{fill:#ffce2e;}</style></defs><title>Asset 2</title></svg>
        <div id="home-step-one">
          <div id="visitor-button" class="home-buttons">Visitor</div>
          <div id="admin-button" class="home-buttons">Admin</div>
        </div>
        <div id="home-step-two">
          <form id="admin-form">
            <input type="password" id="pin" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="text" id="room-name" placeholder="Room Name">
            <div id="enter-button">Enter Lobby</div>
            <div id="create-button">Create</div>
            <div id="join-button">Join</div>
            <div id="create-private">
              <img id="create-private-icon" src="img/create.svg" alt="">
              <span>Create Private</span>
            </div>
            <div id="join-private">Join Private</div>
          </form>
          <input type="image" src="img/back.svg" id="back">
        </div>
        <p id="copyright">©2019 Suntec Singapore. All Rights Reserved. </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--arrow" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
    </span>
    </button>
    <div id="levels-wrapper">
      <ul id="levels-inner">
        <li id="level3">Level 3</li>
        <li id="level4">Level 4</li>
        <li id="level6">Level 6</li>
        <img src="img/logo-white.svg" alt="" id="nav-logo">
      </ul>
    </div>

    <a id="chat" href="login.html"><input type="image" id="chat" src="img/chat.svg"></a>
    <input type="image" id="nav" src="img/navigate.svg">
<!--    <input type="image" id="chat" src="img/chat.svg">-->
    <input type="image" id="to-banq" src="img/banquet.svg">
    <span id="banq-text" class="nav-text">Banquet</span>
    <input type="image" id="to-buffet" src="img/buffet.svg">
    <span id="buffet-text" class="nav-text">Buffet</span>
    <input type="image" id="to-ex" src="img/exhibition.svg">
    <span id="ex-text" class="nav-text">Exhibition</span>
    <input type="image" id="to-conf" src="img/conference.svg">
    <span id="conf-text" class="nav-text">Conference</span>
    <input type="image" id="to-concert" src="img/concert.svg">
    <span id="concert-text" class="nav-text">Concert</span>
    <input type="image" id="to-event" src="img/event.svg">
    <span id="event-text" class="nav-text">Event</span>
    <input type="image" id="to-space" src="img/space.svg">
    <span id="space-text" class="nav-text">Space Only</span>
    <input type="image" id="to-classroom" src="img/classroom.svg">
    <span id="classroom-text" class="nav-text">Classroom</span>
    <input type="image" id="video-control" src="img/video.svg">
    <input type="image" id="play-vid" src="img/play.svg">
    <input type="image" id="mute-vid" src="img/mute.svg">
    <input type="image" id="replay-vid" src="img/reset.svg">
    <a-scene networked-scene="room: lobby; debug: true;">
      <a-assets>
        <img id="buffet-3" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/level3buffet.JPG">
        <img id="space-3" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/level3space.jpg">
        <img id="classroom-3" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/level3classroom.jpg">
        <img id="cluster" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/Hall 406CX Cluster2.jpg">
        <img id="banquet" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/Hall 405BXE 406CXD banquet.jpg">
        <img id="exhibition" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/hall 40123 exhibtion.jpg">
        <img id="concert-2" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/level6concert.jpg">
        <img id="banquet-2" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/level6banq.JPG">
        <img id="event" crossorigin="anonymous" src="img/level6event.jpg">
        <img src="img/landmark.png" id="platform" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- This is where you can change the client's logo -->
        <img src="img/SuntecLvl4Logo.png" id="logo2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <img src="img/SuntecLvl4Logo.png" id="logo3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Videos on the projector screens -->
      <video id="video-src" src="img/3x4border.mp4" playsinline webkit-playsinline></video>
      <video src="img/2x3.mp4" id="video-src2" playsinline webkit-playsinline></video>
  </a-assets>
<a-node></a-node>
<a-video class="clientVideos" id="video-screen" src="#video-src" rotation="0 -90 0" position="100 15.935 17" width="40" height="30"></a-video>
<a-video class="clientVideos" id="video-screen2" src="#video-src2" rotation="0 -90 0" position="100 1.935 6.500" width="60" height="15"></a-video>
<a-sky id="sky" src="#space-3" rotation="0 180 0"></a-sky>
<a-circle id="logo" src="#platform" radius="1" rotation="-90 0 0" position="9.54196 -171.79611 -1.47969" material="" geometry="radius: 27.1"></a-circle>
<a-plane class="clientPictures" id="ex-logo" src="#logo2" position="-20.5 5.9757 -0.41456" rotation="0 90 0" material="side: double; color: #FFFFFF; transparent: true; opacity: 1.5" height="4" width="9" geometry="" visible=""></a-plane>
<a-plane class="clientPictures" id="classroom-logo" src="#logo3" position="59.7606 4.21649 6.21335" rotation="0 -75.05747116213784 0" material="side: double; color: #FFFFFF; transparent: true; opacity: 1.5" height="4" width="9" geometry="" visible="" scale="2.7 2.7 2.7"></a-plane>
<a-entity light="distance:1;type:ambient" id="lightit"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
<script src="js/vendor/AVideoPlayer.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.Wload.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please ignore the home-logo as it is just a logo with animation

Comment: What do you mean by "target two html"? Do you mean two DOM elements?

Comment: You can perform operations on as many HTML elements as you want. This should work. Can you add your HTML?

Comment: Try removing the 1st and second line. Expose the even listener.

Comment: Edit the question to clarify it, don't write it in comments.

Comment: jQuery doesn't mind if you target elements that don't exist. So you can use the same JS with different HTML, and target all the IDs and classes from all of them. The ones that are in a different file will just be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can link single JavaScript file in different HTML file and target them as long it is valid selector.

If you want target multiple selector you can do something like this.

```
$('.chat__main , #chat-content').css("opacity", "0");
```

And of course, don't forgot to include

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tried. nothing happened. feels like my js doesnt want to target the html IDs

Comment: Did you import the jquery library? From what I can see in your updated code, I don't see you importing jQuery library.